# Unable to push clojure project on heroku with dockerfile

Tags: docker, leiningen

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
# We will use Ubuntu for our image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Updating Ubuntu packages

ARG CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION=1.10.1.507


RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install curl wget bzip2 openjdk-8-jdk-headless \
    && curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    #    && curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -bfp /usr/local \
    && rm -rf /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && conda install -y python=3 \
    && conda update conda \
    && curl -o install-clojure https://download.clojure.org/install/linux-install-${CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION}.sh \
    && chmod +x install-clojure \
    && ./install-clojure && rm install-clojure \
    # no need to install lein 
    && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein \
    && chmod a+x lein \
    && mv lein /usr/bin \


    && apt-get -qq -y autoremove \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/log/dpkg.log \
    && conda clean --all --yes

    

ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

RUN conda create -n pyclj python=3.7 && conda install -n pyclj numpy mxnet \
    && conda install -c conda-forge opencv
## To install pip packages into the pyclj environment do
RUN conda run -n pyclj python3 -mpip install numpy opencv-python

FROM openjdk:8-alpine
RUN lein uberjar
COPY target/uberjar/vendo.jar /vendo/app.jar

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/vendo/app.jar", "--server.port=$PORT"]
```

And I'm pushing my project using `git push heroku master`, and I get the error:

```
remote: Step 8/11 : RUN lein uberjar        
remote:  ---> Running in 07533c6b0e9c        
remote: /bin/sh: lein: not found        
remote: The command '/bin/sh -c lein uberjar' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Suggesting that lein wasn't installed. The wget in that first RUN command is supposed to install lein. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `RUN lein` to run the self-install.

Comment: I added it right before RUN lein uberjar but it gives the same error for the RUN lein line